# How do you read a string until a chosen string is found?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsrange

I have a string, NewString, that I want to only display text before the characters "Choices:". I only want to display the text *before* those characters. I tried this but obivously it didnt work. Any suggestions?

```
NewString = [NewString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, @"Chocies:"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"Choices:"];
NSString *newString = [string substringToIndex:range.location];
```

Comment: When you say "string" which string is that?

Comment: When you say "string" which string is that referring to?

Comment: The old one obviously containing `Choices:`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to post that :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to post that :) Actually it was something else since I didn't include the full code here, but it works! Thank you so much! Its been annoying me for days!